# How to use paste0 with input$ in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, paste

This is a follow up question to this [Avoid DRY with 13 sliderInputs and 13 textInputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74509672/avoid-dry-with-13-sliderinputs-and-13-textinputs/74509989#74509989):

**How can I shorten this code:**

```
  sliderValues <- reactive({
    
    data.frame(
      Name = c("A",
               "B",   
               "C"),
      Value = as.character(c(input$a,
                             input$b,
                             input$c
                            )),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  })
```

[image]

**I have tried:**

```
  # Reactive expression to create data frame of all input values ----
  sliderValues <- reactive({
    
    data.frame(
      Name = c(LETTERS[1:3]),
      Value = paste0("input$", letters[1:3]),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  })
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use `sapply` or ...

```
# Reactive expression to create data frame of all input values ----
  sliderValues <- reactive({
    
    data.frame(
      Name = c("A",
               "B",
               "C"),
      Value = as.character(sapply(letters[1:3], function(x) input[[x]])),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    
  })
```