# How to store a shiny reactive data frame as csv on hard drive locally and append new entries

Tags: r, file, events, shiny

This is a follow-up question to this: [How to use paste0 with input$ in shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74510669/how-to-use-paste0-with-input-in-shiny)

I don't know if this is possible and I have been through all the persistent storage history the last years (here is a representative example of a former question: [r shiny: Load data in to form fields from previously persistent stored data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63329561/r-shiny-load-data-in-to-form-fields-from-previously-persistent-stored-data)

**Now I want to create a form in shiny where people can fill in the form and press a button to send the data, this is done with this code:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    # Sidebar to demonstrate various slider options ----
    sidebarPanel(width = 4,
                 setSliderColor(c("DeepPink ", "#FF4500", "Teal"), c(1, 2, 3)),
                 # Input: Simple integer interval ----
                 div(class = "label-left",
                     Map(function(id, lbl) {
                       list(
                         div(style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:middle; width: 300px;",sliderInput(id, lbl, min = 0, max = 3, value = 0, width = "250px")),
                         div(style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:middle; width: 150px;",textInput(paste0("txt_", id), label = NULL, value = 0, width = "40px" ))
                       )
                     }, c("a", "b", "c"), c("A", "B", "C"))
                 )
    ),
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      titlePanel("Sliders"),
      # Output: Table summarizing the values entered ----
      tableOutput("values")
      
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  Map(function(id) {
    list(
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("txt_", id)]], {
        if(as.numeric(input[[paste0("txt_", id)]]) != input[[id]])
        {
          updateSliderInput(
            session = session,
            inputId = id,
            value = input[[paste0("txt_", id)]]
          ) # updateSliderInput
        }#if
      }),
      observeEvent(input[[id]], {
        if(as.numeric(input[[paste0("txt_", id)]]) != input[[id]])
        {
          updateTextInput(
            session = session,
            inputId = paste0("txt_", id),
            value = input[[id]]
          ) # updateTextInput
          
        }#if
      })
    )
  }, c("a", "b", "c"))
  
  # Reactive expression to create data frame of all input values ----
  sliderValues <- reactive({
    
    data.frame(
      Name = c("A",
               "B",
               "C"),
      Value = as.character(c(input$a,
                             input$b,
                             input$c
      )),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    
  })
  
  # Show the values in an HTML table ----
  output$values <- renderTable({
    sliderValues()
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And NOW I would like to save the actual filled in data to **the hard disk** as csv or any other format. And if the same user comes again next time the new data should be appended to  the existing data.

Is this possible?

Comment: It is not possible to read a data file from local hard drive (security issue). Workaround would be to download the file, then upload it next time. Maybe it would be possible to store data in a cookie like this [example](https://itecnote.com/tecnote/r-how-to-access-browser-session-cookies-from-within-shiny-app/)

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Do you have any pointer how to download the dataframe and upload next time?

Comment: There are many resources about these subjects.

Comment: How are your hosting your app? Are you using shinyapps.io or e.g. a local shiny-server?

Comment: no unfortunately no local shiny-server. I use shinyapps.io. Many thanks @ismirsehregal.

Comment: Then you'll need to use remote storage (please see [this related article](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/persistent-data-storage.html)), implement the upload/download procedure as mentioned by @HubertL or you save the data on the client side (e.g. browsers localStorage) via e.g. library([shinyStorePlus](https://github.com/oobianom/shinyStorePlus)).

Comment: How do you identify/autorize users? How many distinct users are you expecting to work with your Shiny application?

Comment: The app is open without restrictions. It is a specific calculator. It is relevant for a few hundred of users.

Comment: As the users are not authorised how then do you plan to identify specific users on the server side?

Comment: Maybe I am not clear and maybe it is much more clearer the I can express. If you open the above script in the browser (I will make it availabe via shinyapps.io) then you can move 3 slider. Each movement changes the value in a dataframe. When you finished to insert the desired data, then there should be a button to download this dataframe to your desired path. Nothing more and nothing less.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an `app.R` that does the required actions from your comments.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)
library(openxlsx)

defaultDF <- data.frame(Name = c("A", "B", "C"),
                        Value = rep(0L, 3))

MyColors = c("DeepPink ", "#FF4500", "Teal")

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    # Sidebar to demonstrate various slider options ----
    sidebarPanel(width = 4,
                 setSliderColor(MyColors, 
                                c(1:3)),
                 # Input: Simple integer interval ----
                 div(class = "label-left",
                     Map(function(id, lbl, val) {
                       list(
                         div(style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:middle; width: 300px;",
                             sliderInput(id, lbl, min = 0, max = 3, value = val, width = "250px")),
                         div(style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:middle; width: 150px;",
                             textInput(paste0("txt_", id), label = NULL, value = 0, width = "40px" ))
                       )
                     }, defaultDF %>% select(Name) %>% pull(), 
                     defaultDF %>% select(Name) %>% pull(), 
                     defaultDF %>% select(Value) %>% pull())
                 ),
                 downloadButton("xlsxDownload", "Download dataframe"),
                 fileInput(
                   "xlsxUpload",
                   "Files with stored values",
                   #placeholder = "Select files",
                   #buttonLabel = "Обзор",
                   #accept = c(".xml",".zip"),
                   accept = c(".xlsx"),
                   multiple = F
                 )
    ),
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      titlePanel("Sliders"),
      # Output: Table summarizing the values entered ----
      tableOutput("values")
      
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  currentDF <- reactiveVal(defaultDF)
  
  # Show the values in an HTML table ----
  output$values <- renderTable({
    currentDF()
  })
  output$xlsxDownload <- downloadHandler(
    filename = 
      function() { "myDataframe.xlsx"
      },
    content = 
      function(file) {
        openxlsx::write.xlsx(
          currentDF(), 
          file)
      }
    
  )
  
  observe({
    file1 <- input$xlsxUpload
    if (!is.null(file1)) {
      
    
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file1$datapath)
    req(file1)
    validate(need(ext %in% c("xlsx"), 'All files must have extension xlsx')) # Add all other validation checks as well


    transformedData <- openxlsx::read.xlsx(file1$datapath)
    #do necessary checks and data transformations here
    transformedData
    currentDF(transformedData)
    }
  })
  
  observe({
    cdf <- currentDF()
    Map(function(Nm) updateSliderInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = Nm,
      value = cdf %>% filter(Name == Nm) %>% select(Value) %>% pull()
    ),
    c("A", "B", "C")
    )
  })
  
  observe({
    cdf <- currentDF()
    Map(function(Nm) updateTextInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = paste0("txt_", Nm),
      value = cdf %>% filter(Name == Nm) %>% select(Value) %>% pull()
    ),
    c("A", "B", "C")
    )
  })

  toListen <- reactive({
    list(input$A, input$B, input$C)
  })
  toListen2 <- reactive({
    list(input$txt_A, input$txt_B, input$txt_C)
  })
  
  observeEvent(toListen(),{ Map(function(id) {cdf <- currentDF() 
      cdf$Value[cdf$Name == id] <- input[[id]]
      currentDF(cdf)
  },
  c("A", "B", "C")
  )
  }
  )
  
  observeEvent(toListen2(),{ Map(function(id) {cdf <- currentDF() 
  cdf$Value[cdf$Name == id] <- input[[paste0("txt_", id)]]
  currentDF(cdf)
  },
  c("A", "B", "C")
  )
  }
  )
 
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

It allows:

- to save and load a xlsx file with dataframe containing settings (values of A, B and C) on the client side.
  [image]
- to change this dataframe when slider is moved and or text is input.
  [image]
- to adjust positions of sliders / values in text inputs and rendered dataframe when the flie is loaded and/or any of the input controls value changes.
  [image]