# In a shiny app how can I let the user choose the filename and directory to download with write.table

Tags: r, file, shiny, download, write.table

This is a follow-up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74537975/how-to-store-a-shiny-reactive-data-frame-as-csv-on-hard-drive-locally-and-append)

Now I somehow managed to download the reactive dataframe to my hard drive (!not server or working directory) and append each new entry as new line with `write.table`.

Interestingly `write.csv` does not work because it does not allow `append` argument https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2016-August/441011.html.

With this minimal working app, I would like to know how I can get the user to choose a directory and a filname to download there. Now I have this absolut path: `file = "C:/Users/yourname/Downloads/my_df.csv"` which works. But I don't know if it will work for other user!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    
    sidebarPanel(width = 4,
                 sliderInput("a", "A", min = 0, max = 3, value = 0, width = "250px"),
                 actionButton("submit", "Submit")
                 ),
    
    mainPanel(
      titlePanel("Sliders"),
      tableOutput("values")
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
 
  sliderValues <- reactive({
    data.frame(Name = c("A"), Value = as.character(c(input$a)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  })
  
  output$values <- renderTable({
    sliderValues()
  }) 
  
  # Save the values to a CSV file on the hard disk ----
  saveData <- reactive({write.table(sliderValues(), file = "C:/Users/yourname/Downloads/my_df.csv", col.names=!file.exists("C:/Users/yourname/Downloads/my_df.csv"), append = TRUE) })
  
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    saveData()
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The requirement is that the user should see a modal dialog ui with the question "In which folder with which filename you want to download?".
Quasi like the things we do daily if we download from the internet.

Comment: Its not a download if you are using `write.table`. Its being written directly by the server to the server's disk space. This will be the user's disk space if they are also the person running the server. But its not a download. A better Q would be "Path to save file to?" and never ever ever put this on a public server because its a massive potential security hole.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Could you please explain the massive security hole or give me some idea how to manage this task?

Comment: Why don't you use `downloadHandler`?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Do you know if we can append data to an existing csv with downloadHandler?

Comment: No. `downloadHandler` just downloads a file.

Comment: If your shiny app says "where do you want to save this file?" and the user can answer "C:\windows\system\windows.exe" and you let it overwrite an existing file then the user has just trashed an important system file on the server. Why do you want the user to be able to write on the server? The user can't get that file unless they are running the server, but that's not true if this is running as a service for users online.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you very much this makes sense. The idea of doing this way was to overcome the main security problem when collecting data. The first question is always where do you save the data. And saving online on the cloud independent where is no option. Therefore I thought that if the form is filled in, the user can save it on his usb stick etc... Meanwhile I got more light in my brain an I have done it with DT::datatable(...,options = list(...,buttons  = c('csv', 'excel',.....`. I really appreciate taking your time and sharing your expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now solved it this way:

I realized that I have two options:

1. As suggested by @Stéphane Laurent using [`downloadhandler`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/downloadhandler)
2. Using `DT::datatable()`

I have decided to use number 2. Many thanks to all of your inputs!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("a", "A", min = 0, max = 3, value = 0, width = "250px"),
  titlePanel("Sliders"),
  dataTableOutput("sliderValues", width="450px")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  sliderValues <- reactive({
    df <- data.frame(
      Name = "A", 
      Value = as.character(c(input$a)), 
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>% 
      pivot_wider(names_from = Name, values_from = Value)
    
    return(df)
  })

  
  # Show the values in an HTML table in a wider format----
  output$sliderValues <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(sliderValues(),
                  extensions = c('Buttons'),
                  options = list(
                    dom = 'frtBip',
                    buttons = list(list(extend = 'excel', filename = paste0("myname-", Sys.Date())))
                  )
    )
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]