# Why does my use of Shiny downloadHandler() function work so differently from the shinyFilesButton() function when directory browsing?

Tags: r, security, shiny

The code below is a minimal working example of action buttons for the user to save a numeric input using `downloadHandler()` and to delete the file storing that input using `shinyFilesButton()`. Ultimately, I'd like the user to be able to manage files as you would an Excel or Word document: you can save a document to your local computer, load a document from your local computer, and similarly delete a document from your local computer; but in this R case, only `.rds` files containing simple numeric inputs (scenarios). Is this feasible in R Shiny?

What I don't understand about this example is:

1. With respect to the delete action button (using `shinyFilesButton()`), it is far more restrictive than the save action button (using `downloadHandler()`) in terms of directories that can be browsed, and there's a difference in browsing scope for  the delete action button when this code is run unsaved versus when it is run saved to the computer (where you get the "Run App" button on the upper right hand corner of the R Studio console window). Can the save action, using `shinyFilesButton()`, be made as flexible as `downloadHandler()` in terms of directories that can be accessed
2. An observation only, but the user can always use the Save button (using `downloadHandler()`) to delete a file by highlighting the file and hitting the delete button on the keyboard. But the Delete action button with its `shinyFilesButton()` is safer because it only makes `.rds` files available for deletion.
3. I wonder what security risks this file management structure poses for users and how they can be mitigated. The only types of data that will be saved/uploaded/eligible for deletion will be simple matrix numeric inputs and short numbered lists of character strings. The `.rds` files will not contain sensitive data nor any type of customer ID info. They are only scenario inputs that are saved and managed for future replicability by the user. Inputs can become very involved and intricate so retrieval is important.

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("obs", "User inputs a value:", 10, min = 1, max = 100),
  downloadButton("save_btn", "Save input"),
  actionButton('modal_delete','Delete saved input')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$save_btn <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste0("scenario", ".rds")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      saveRDS(input$obs, file)
    }
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$modal_delete, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      shinyFilesButton("delete_input","Select file to delete","Select file",multiple = FALSE),
      actionButton("delete_btn", "Delete")
    ))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$modal_delete, {
    saved_files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.rds$")
    updateSelectInput(session, "delete_input", choices = saved_files)
  })
  
  shinyFileChoose(input, "delete_input", roots = c(wd = getwd(), root = "/"), filetypes = c('', 'rds'))
  
  observe({
    saved_files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.rds$")
    updateSelectInput(session, "delete_input", choices = saved_files)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$delete_btn, {
    file <- parseFilePaths(roots = c(wd = getwd()), input$delete_input)
    if (file$datapath[1] != "" ||
        !is.null(input$delete_input) || 
        input$delete_input != "") {
      unlink(file$datapath[1])
      saved_files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.rds$")  
      updateSelectInput(session, "delete_input", choices = saved_files)
    } 
    removeModal() 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I was after the same thing some time ago. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74669055/in-a-shiny-app-how-can-i-let-the-user-choose-the-filename-and-directory-to-downl) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74537975/how-to-store-a-shiny-reactive-data-frame-as-csv-on-hard-drive-locally-and-append) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75266539/how-to-pass-user-input-to-filename-in-r-shiny-downloadhandler). What I have learned is:  to be continued....

Comment: ... continued: First link comment by @Spacedman: If your shiny app says "where do you want to save this file?" and the user can answer "C:\windows\system\windows.exe" and you let it overwrite an existing file then the user has just trashed an important system file on the server. Why do you want the user to be able to write on the server? The user can't get that file unless they are running the server, but that's not true if this is running as a service for users online. –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Tarjae's and other comments, below is the code I am settling on. Note that I removed any file-delete functionality because everything I found or tried was extremely limiting. The user can always delete a saved `.rds` file through the normal channels using Windows, just like any saved Excel `.xls` or Word `.doc` file. Further note that files are automatically saved as `.rds`, eliminating the risk cited by @Spacedman of writing over a crucial operating file such as a `.exe` file.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h5(strong("Matrix inputs:")),
  matrixInput(
    "base_input", 
    value = matrix(rep(1,2), 2, 1, dimnames = list(c("A","B"),NULL)),
    rows = list(extend = FALSE,  names = TRUE),
    cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
    class = "numeric"
  ),
  
  h5(strong("Multiplies inputs by 4:")),
  tableOutput("result_table"),
  
  h5(strong("Input scenario manager:")),
  actionButton('clear_btn', 'Clear'),
  downloadButton("save_btn", "Save"),
  actionButton('modal_upload','Upload')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$save_btn <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste0("scenario", ".rds")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      saveRDS(input$base_input, file)
    }
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$modal_upload, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      fileInput("upload_file_input", "Choose a file to upload:", accept = c('.rds'))
    ))
  })
  
  observe({
    if (!is.null(input$upload_file_input)) {
      uploaded_values <- readRDS(input$upload_file_input$datapath)
      updateMatrixInput(session, "base_input", value = uploaded_values)
      removeModal()
    }
  })
  
  output$upload_file <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      input$upload_file_input
    },
    content = function(file) {
      file.copy(input$upload_file_input$datapath, file)
    }
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$clear_btn, {
    default_values <- matrix(rep(1,2), 2, 1, dimnames = list(c("A","B"),NULL))
    updateMatrixInput(session, "base_input", value = default_values)
  })
  
  matrix_data <- reactive({
    matrix_df <- as.data.frame(
      matrix(
        input$base_input * 4, 2, 1, dimnames = list(c("A","B"), NULL)
      )
    )
    colnames(matrix_df) <- "Matrix x 4"
    matrix_df
  })
  
  output$result_table <- renderTable({
    matrix_data()
  }, rownames = TRUE, colnames = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```