file.copy with downloadButton in Shiny
I would like to create a downloadButton which downloads certain files. The problem I'm facing is that I can't specify the destination path of the file in a Quarto dashboard. For that reason I'm trying to use file.copy which copies the file to the right destination path. Here is a simple reproducible example:
---
title: "Test"
format: dashboard
server: shiny
---

```{r}
library(shiny)
```

```{r}
p("Choose a dataset to download.")
selectInput("dataset", "Dataset", choices = c("mtcars", "airquality"))
downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")
```

    
```{r}
#| context: server

# The requested dataset
data <- reactive({
      get(input$dataset)
})

output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        # Use the selected dataset as the suggested file name
        paste0(input$dataset, ".csv")
      },
      content = function(file) {
        # Write the dataset to the `file` that will be downloaded
        write.csv(data(), file)
        file.copy(from = paste0("/Users/quinten/Downloads/", file), 
                  to = paste0("/Users/quinten/", file))
      }
)
```

Output:

The file always returns in my Downloads folder which happens automatically so I tried to use file.copy to copy the file to a different folder but that doesn't work. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to use the file.copy option in a downloadButton module?

see my comments here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77716311/why-does-my-use-of-shiny-downloadhandler-function-work-so-differently-from-thewith the links provided.

file is the full path to the tempfile not the input filename.  Try file.copy(file, paste0("/Users/quinten/", input$dataset, ".csv")) which should create a second copy in the specified location regardless of where the user chooses to save the file.

@lroha This doesn’t work, and fundamentally cannot work. The code in the download handler is executed on the server, and the server obviously has no knowledge of or access to the client’s filesystem. — And even if the code were executed on the frontend, it would be a huge problem if the code of a website could override where files are stored on the user’s system. This must be fully controlled by the user (otherwise a malicious website could override arbitrary files).

@KonradRudolph - I was making the assumption given that OP hardcoded their user directory in the example they intended to run the dashboard locally for their own use.

@TarJae, Thank you very much for your comment. I still don't understand why when I use the downloadHandler my file always automatically goes to the Download folder. I'm not able to specify a certain destination folder.

@Quinten See my comment above.
